# JS - Sort select2 response alphabetically

Tags: javascript

I am using this select2:

```
jQuery("#assign_users").select2({
    openOnEnter: false,
    ajax: {
        url: '/profile/return_user_select/',
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

and I get:

```
[{'id': 12, 'text': 'C C'}, {'id': 13, 'text': 'A A'}, {'id': 14, 'text': 'B B'}]
```

but, I need it to be in alphabetical order: AA, BB, CC...

I tried this

```
sortResults: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text))
```

But it doesnt work.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```js
const x = [{'id': 12, 'text': 'C C'}, {'id': 13, 'text': 'A A'}, {'id': 14, 'text': 'B B'}];

x.sort((a, b) => (a.text > b.text));
console.log(x);
```